# jQuery function speed control

Tags: jquery, performance, function

I'm trying to animate and control the speed of this function :
the function changes the current background to a different one , right now it changes instantly ...

this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        jQuery("#lit").hover(function(){
        jQuery("body").css("background-image", "url(img/2.jpg)" ); 

               }).mouseleave(function(){
              jQuery("body").css("background-image", "url(img/1.jpg)"  ); 

                  });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a transition

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        jQuery("#lit").hover(function(){
        jQuery("body").css("background-image", "url(img/2.jpg)" ); 
        jQuery("body").css("transition", "background-image 0.5s ease-in-out" ); 

               }).mouseleave(function(){
              jQuery("body").css("background-image", "url(img/1.jpg)"  ); 
              jQuery("body").css("transition", "background-image 0.5s ease-in-out" ); 
                  });
        });
```